# In present perfect tense, do 'for' and 'since' imply the action is still going on?

Tags: present-perfect, for, since

Consider the 3 cases:

1. I have made a lot of cookies.
2. I have made a lot of cookies since the morning.
3. I have made a lot of cookies for 2 hours.

To my ears, (1) implies the person is not making cookies anymore, while (2) and (3) imply the person may still be making cookies at the time of speaking.

The same situation can be seen in:

4. I have cleaned the house: The person is not cleaning the house anymore at the time of speaking.
5. I have cleaned the house since the morning/for 2 hours: The person might still be cleaning the house at the time of speaking.

Thus, does the words "since" and "for" in present perfect imply the continuity of the action up to the point of speaking?

Comment: (3) and (5) are not idiomatic English. _I have been making cookies for two hours_ (I'm still doing so) OR _I made cookies for two hours_ (but now I've stopped baking). See [this related question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/55929/present-perfect-with-since-or-for?rq=1).

Comment: #3 is not idiomatic. We'd say *I **made** a lot of cookies **in** 2 hours,* or *I made cookies **for** 2 hours.* Or possibly *I **have been making** a lot of cookies for 2 hours*.

Comment: @KateBunting If (3) and (5) are not idiomatic, then how about "I have worked here for a year/since last year"? This common expression has the same grammatical structure as (3) and (5).

Comment: @ASlowLearner  But "last year" is a *point* in time, and "two hours" is a *span* of time.  I think that accounts for some of the difference in grammar.

Comment: @stangdon but we can still say "I have worked here for a year", as said in my comment.

Comment: One piece of the puzzle is that specifying a quantity of cookies ("a lot") portrays the event as having an intrinsic endpoint (linguists call such an event *telic*), so "in" rather than "for" would be expected to express the duration. Compare: "I read the book for an hour (but didn't finish it)" vs. "I read the book in an hour" (i.e. got to the end of the book).